# ASP FileUpload Works on locahost but not on production

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

So I am having an interesting problem that I hope has an easy solution that I am just overlooking.

I have an asp:FileUpload control that I am processing to upload to a SQL DB.  When I run the project locally, this works flawlessly.  Now when running through production (IIS 7.5) I get a silent failure.  I can upload files no issue as long as they aren't of the new Office format (docx, pptx, etc).  The page just reloads and there is no file in my DB.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Sorry guys.  This was a stupid mistake on my part.  I didn't have the DB updated in production to reflect the correct varchar length so the DB section was failing.  Thanks for all who considered this issue.

Comment: post the source code you have implemented to upload files.

Comment: @Nudier Okay, I think I added the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `FileUpload` on another environment , tou can use `Server.MapPath`

In order to adress file with relative path

```
if (yourControl.HasFile) 
{
      var result = Server.MapPath("..."); //You adapt your Server.MapPath
       ..... 
}
```